# Deploying a Django app with Heroku error: non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

Tags: django, heroku, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am having trouble deploying my first Django app to Heroku on Mac (Mavericks).

Since updating to mavericks I have had some package versioning issues and I wonder if its causing this:

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES

                    numpy: no

                           * You must install numpy 1.4 or later to build

                           * matplotlib.
Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

Scipy, numpy and matplotlib dont seem to play well together. Here is my requirements.txt file:

```
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django==1.4.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
docutils==0.11
geopy==0.95.1
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.8
numpy==1.7.1
matplotlib==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.1
scipy==0.12.0
south==0.8.1
static==0.4
virtualenv==1.10.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

As you may be able to see, I have numpy 1.7.1. 
I have read that a solution is to remove matplotlib, deploy and then re add it, so Numpy has already been loaded, but when I tried removing matplotlib then deploying this I get the error:

```
File "/tmp/pip-build-u27984/scipy/setup.py", line 145, in setup_package

   from numpy.distutils.core import setup

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I found changing my django version to 1.5 made it work.

```
dj-database-url==0.2.2
dj-static==0.0.5
django==1.5
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
docutils==0.11
geopy==0.95.1
gunicorn==18.0
httplib2==0.8
lucene-querybuilder==0.1.6
numpy==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.1
six==1.3.0
south==0.8.1
static==0.4
virtualenv==1.10.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```